# Google Cloud Messaging notification functions?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Now that I got GCM working, I am looking for a way to do in app functions when a message is received, or notification is clicked.

Sadly I can not find anything about this.
I do however remember vaguely that these things where possible.

I know this is not an good Stackoverflow question, but I really need an answer to this.

Comment: What do you mean by `in app functions`? You mean do something concrete when a message is received?

Comment: Yep, like reading the text send with the notification and save it with sharedpreferences for example. So that I can also show the whole text of the notification in my Home screen for example.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done extending an `IntentService`:

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMprocess extends IntentService {
  public GCMprocess() { super("GCMIntentService"); }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
    final GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    final String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if ((!extras.isEmpty()) && (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))) {
      // This condition would test whether there's a field named code which is called foo
      if (extras.getString("code").equals("foo")) {
        doWhateverYouNeed();
      }
    }

    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
  }
}
```

As this is also a `Service`, you need to register it in your `AndroidManifest` file:

```
<service android:name="com.foo.bar.GCMprocess" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But it doesn't seem to work for me? In the condition check I try to call a function (with overload) from the MainActivity like this:    MainActivity  main= new MainActivity();    main.updateText(extras.getString("code")); But that function doesn't then update the TextView, while it should?

Comment: Yes, because you're creating a new instance of `MainActivity`, which doesn't correspond to the one you're seeing on screen. You have to use a way to communicate this `ServiceIntent` with your `MainActivity`, and the easier way that comes to my mind is using a local `BroadcastReceiver` on your `MainActivity` and send an `Intent` from your `GCMprocess` implementation. This would be a good example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html